# Subclass of set is set isn't it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have:

"B is a class."

"A is a subclass of B."

"B is a set."

I want the proof or counterexample of the next statement:

"A is a set".

Intuition:

A must not be bigger than B.

Any ideas?

p.s. This question is perhaps connected with foundations. So let them be a NBG. (any others are also welcome)

----edited:
I see minuses. Please write in comments why this question about elementary set/class theory is not good, so I'll improve it. (At least with formal verification of its proof.)

Comment: Classes aren't part of ZFC so it doesn't make sense to ask this question in that context.

Comment: Since ZFC only describes *sets*, you are perhaps interested in the case of [a theory like NGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) which allows for (proper) classes (in addition to sets).  The claim is true there, the intersection of a class and a set is a set.

Comment: @hardmath: In ZFC, one can still speak of classes as being predicates in the ambient logic. They aren't members of the universe, but something one can work with anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are given by predicates. The axiom of subsets says that whenever $S$ is a set and $P$ is a predicate, then there is a set $T$ whose elements are precisely those elements of $S$ satisfying $P$.

I.e. if $S$ is a set, then so is the class $\{ x \in S \mid P(x) \}$.

Of all elements satisfying $P$ are elements of $S$, then $T$ is precisely the set of objects satisfying $P$.

The axiom of subsets sometimes goes by other names, such as restricted comprehension or separation.

(also, it's often given an axiom schema, rather than a single axiom)

Answer (score 1):

A class is set if it is an element of another class. If $B$ is a set then we can form the power set $\mathcal{P(B)}$ and then $A \in \mathcal{P(B)}$.

Comment: T.Gunn, Thanks, but powerset consists of sets. So it is not a proof of my statement. (look the page #234 of Mendelson's Introduction to Logic )

Comment: @GeorgyDunaev The elements of any class are sets by definition. I don't understand the complaint.

Comment: @T._Gunn At first I thought that you are right, so I've wrote the sketch of proof in Metamath. But then I faced problem of substitution of class to set variable. As you can see on p.236 of Mendelson. "Axiom W" contains quantifier "for all u". The lowercase "u" in this book means "for all  U ( M(U) -> ... )" which means that u is a set. That is not a hypothesis because it is an assertion.

Comment: Maybe you are right, because of implicit use of separation axiom or other reasons. I may misinterpret your words or may not have enough skill in verification. Hurkyl is certainly right because of this proof:  http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/ssex.html Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Georgy It is possible that there are two different ways to write the powerset axiom. One could say that the powerset of $B$ consists of all subclasses of $B$ and hence all subclasses of a set are sets by my proof. Alternatively, one could say that the powerset consists of subsets (subclasses which are themselves sets) which is equivalent to the first axiom by Hurkyl's proof.

Answer (score 0):

Halmos defines a class as a set of sets.  So in your example $A$ and $B$ both behave as a set and a class.  $A \subset B$ is equivalent to both statements "A is a subclass of B" and "A is a subset of B"

Define $A$ and $B$ as follows, where each $a_n$ and $b_m$ are in this example finite countable sets:

$$A := \{ a_0, a_1, a_2, ... , a_n \}$$
$$B := \{ b_0, b_1, b_2, ... , b_n, ... , b_m  \}$$

If $A\subset B$, then $\forall a_i \in A \implies \exists b_k \in B$ such that $b_k = a_i$ and there would be some set of $b_k \not \in A$ and card$(A) < $ card$(B)$.